# Preventing Spoofed Forms

Tags: php, security

I have a php page that submits form to itself.
I wanted to add a check where I can possibly stop basic cross site forgery.

my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

(...) //some code

$secret = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 1, 2);
$_SESSION["secret"] = $secret;
$auth = $secret;

?>

(...)

<form id="form" name="form" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>" method="post">

(...)

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $auth; ?>" />

(...)

<?php

(...)

//as a debug I just tried to display
echo $_POST["id"];
echo "=";
echo $_SESSION["secret"];

(...)

?>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

But both `id` and `secret` never returns the same value.
Why is that? What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE**

So, I tried an answer here by Samuel Cook, as also suggested by the comment of Jon Stirling:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["secret"])){
    $secret = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 1, 2);
    $_SESSION["secret"] = $secret;
    $auth = $secret;
}
```

But now if there is no `$_SESSION["secret"]`
The page returns:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
```

I understand why, its because secret is only being set if the session variable is present.
Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**

Moved the check before generating a new session key and is only checking if there is a post of id. **works well now** thanks.

Comment: Is it because you regenerate $secret at the top of the page and assign it to the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point when you debug code executes, the secret has changed:

```
echo $_POST["id"]; // previous secret
echo "=";
echo $_SESSION["secret"]; // new secret
```

As long as you do your check for a match at the beginning of the script (**before generating the next secret**) it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once You Open A page $auth Will generate and i will be in hidden field after submiting $_SESSION["secret"] will change because $secret will generate new key but $_POST['id'] is old one which coming from Post method.

Comment: Ahh, i guess i should only generate a new session key if the ID is not present?

Comment: Yes
if(empty($_POST['id'])){
//generate new key
}

Answer (score 0):

you are always generating a new `$secret` therefore it will always be different. You could check to see if the `$_SESSION['secret']` exists, and if it doesn't then create a new variable. Something like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["secret"])){
    $secret = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 1, 2);
    $_SESSION["secret"] = $secret;
    $auth = $secret;
}
```